# function() vs. return function() inside outer function

Tags: python, function

```
def print_func():
    print("Hello, how you doin'?")


def other_func():
    return print_func()

def other_func2():
    print_func()
```

Can somebody explain what is the difference between other_func and other_func2? 
I saw that in one code and I am not sure what is the difference between those 2 functions.

Comment: nothing. Function that don't `return` a value return `None`, as does `print`, so `other_func2()` prints the text, then returns `None`, while `other_func` prints the text, then returns the return value of `print_func()`, which is also `None`. Functionally equivalent.

Note that if `print_func` returned a value, it would be quite different.

Answer (score 2):

This function

```
def other_func():
    return print_func()
```

returns the result of `print_func()`

This one

```
def other_func2():
    print_func()
```

always returns `None` because its definition does not contains a return statement.

Unfortunately, this example is not relevant. Since `print_func()` have no return statement too, it always returns `None`. For that reason, `other_func()` will always returns `None`...

Consider this example to better understand function definitions and return values:

```
def funcNoReturn():
    print("funcNoReturn() always return None!")

def funcA():
    # Returns an int value
    return 42 + 100

def funcB():
    return "a string value..."

print(funcNoReturn())
print(funcA())
print(funcB())
```

When executed, the output is:

```
funcNoReturn() always return None!
None
142
a string value...
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example might help you:

```
def print_func():
    print("Hello, how you doin'?")
    return "printed"


def other_func():
    return print_func()

def other_func2():
    print_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = other_func()
    s2 = other_func2()
    print(s1)
    print(s2)
```

The thing is that other_func returns a value which can be stored in s1. While other_func2 does not return anything. To show you that I added a return statement to print_func().

Answer (score 0):

**other_func** returns the value returned by `print_func()`. As there is no explicit `return` instruction in `print_func()`, it returns the default value `None`. So other_func returns `None`, after execution of `print_func()`.

**other_func2** returns `None` (default returned value), after execution of print_func().

So both are finally doing the same. However **other_func** may lead to confusion for the reader, because of the instruction `return print_func()` knowing that print_func() has no return instruction.

Answer (score 0):

All your functions, configured in this setup, return `None`.

That is the default return value for functions, one that is returned if no `return` is specified.

Your `other_func()`, however, returns the return value of `print_func()`. Given that you haven't specified any return value for `print_func()` it returns `None` making `other_func()` return `None` as well.

If you had specified any return value for `print_func()` - it would be picked up by `other_func()`, but not by `other_func2()`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in python **must** return something (unless they throw an exception). Therefore all python functions have an implicit `return None` and the end of their code

```
def fun():
   #<your code>
   return None
```

so

```
def f():
   pass

v = f()  # v is None
```

Your functions actually look like this to the python interpreter

```
def print_func():
    print("Hello, how you doin'?")
    return None

def other_func():
    return print_func()  # === return None
    return None  # never encountered

def other_func2():
    print_func()
    return None
```

Hence both do exactly the same thing as long as `print_func` returns `None`. If `print_func` was instead defined as

```
def print_func():
    print("Hello, how you doin'?")
    return 0
```

then `other_func` would now return `0` while `other_func2` would still return `None`.